# Fill values inside div with jquery load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div class="row" id="user-details-div">

    <form id="add-user-form"  method="POST" >

        <div class="form-group">
            <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control" id="mobile" name="firstname" placeholder="Ad" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="pwdMask">
                <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control" name="lastname" placeholder="Soyad" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <button id="new-user-btn"  onclick="loadUserInfoView()" type="button">Ekle/Duzelt</button>
        <button id="new-user-btn"  onclick="saveUser()" type="button">Ekle/Duzelt</button>

    </form>
</div>
```

WHen button is clicked i bring another div into that div:

```
function loadUserInfoView() {
    //takes id and adds to url
    $("#user-details-div").load(url);
}
```

so it goes here

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{id}")
public String getUserById(Model model, @PathVariable("id") String id) {
    model.addAttribute("user", service.internalUserService.findById(Long.valueOf(id)));

    return "user-detail :: user-details";
}
```

this is **user-detail html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
</head>



    <div th:fragment="user-details">

        <table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <input type="text" th:field="*{user.firstname}">Ad</input><br>
                <input type="text" th:field="*{user.lastname}">Soyad</input><br>


                <button id="new-user-btn"  onclick="addEditUserInfo()" type="button">Ekle/Duzelt</button>
            </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>

    </div>
```

So to sum up, there is a form with 2 input fields. If user fills inputs and clicks add button, it sends post but if clicks other button, it brings the user info. It loads another div.

But that another div is also has same fields with the current div.

So instead of putting div, can i put fields one by one?

Answer (score 2):

1. user-detail.html: Don't send full HTML frame (`doctype`, `html`, `body`).
2. Normally semantic data is transmitted using a data-semantic format (i.e, JSON). So you would send a JSON like `{firstName:'Foo',lastName:'Bar'}` and process that using JS client-side to update the form fields.
3. If you don't want to do that, you can parse the data from the loaded HTML. For instance:

```
$.ajax(url,{complete:function(data){
    var $fragment=$(data),
        firstName=$(':input[name=firstName]',$fragment).val(),
        lastName=$(':input[name=lastName]',$fragment).val(),
        $myForm=$('#user-details-div');
    $(':input[name=firstName]',$myForm).val(firstName);
    $(':input[name=lastName]',$myForm).val(lastName);
}})
```

Comment: I could not understand 2. How can i put json to `<div th:fragment="user-details">` without using ajax call?

Comment: You do use an ajax call to retrieve the JSON. As for "how do I do AJAX", the question is too broad for the scope of stackoverflow, I recommend starting with a tutorial, for example https://www.quackit.com/json/tutorial/json_with_http_jquery.cfm .